# How to remove specify version of kernel, fedora?

Tags: fedora, kernel, dnf

I downgrade my kernel to 4.20.16-200.fc29.x86_64 after it got updated to kernel-5.0.4-200.fc29.x86_64.

Now when I tried to remove it using dnf, and I am getting this `No match for argument: kernel-5.0.4-200.fc29.x86_6` if I execute `sudo dnf remove kernel-5.0.4-200.fc29.x86_64`

Also tried `sudo dnf remove kernel*5.0.4-200.fc29.x86_64` and I am getting this

```
Error: 
 Problem: package kernel-5.0.4-200.fc29.x86_64 requires kernel-core-uname-r = 5.0.4-200.fc29.x86_64, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - problem with installed package kernel-5.0.4-200.fc29.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Adding `--skip-broken` still render the same result.

What is the proper way to remove unwanted kernel?